# Tinymce failed to load skin.min.css in android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, tinymce

I am using [angular2-tinymce](https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce) library to work with tinymce editor for **android** in my project. It is perfectly working in browser using **ionic serve**. But when i tried to run in android, **skin.min.css** file is not loaded and as a result, tinymce editor is not there in the app.
In my project **src** folder:

[image]

And in my project **platforms** folder:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to override the skin path(**skin_url**) of **TinymceModule** to load the css files from assets folder in android.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddProgressNotePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AddProgressNotePage),
    TinymceModule.withConfig({
      skin_url: 'assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray' // Need to provide a fixed path
    })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my angular8 project, I have fixed by adding skin_url.

In my case:

```
    import { TinymceModule } from 'angular2-tinymce';
 
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...

        TinymceModule.withConfig({
           skin_url: '../assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray'
        }),

      ],
      ...
    })
    export class EditorModule { }
```